# Can't start sphinxsearch - failed to open *.lock

Tags: sphinx

When running `sudo service sphinxsearch start` it gives me this error:

```
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: compat_sphinxql_magics=1 is deprecated; please update your application and config
listening on 127.0.0.1:3307
precaching index 'items_item'
WARNING: index 'items_item': preload: failed to open /var/data/items_item.lock: Permission denied; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'reviews_feedback'
WARNING: index 'reviews_feedback': preload: failed to open /var/data/reviews_feedback.lock: Permission denied; NOT SERVING
FATAL: no valid indexes to serve
 ERROR.
```

Here is my conf file:

```
index items_item
{
    type              = rt

    # List all fields
    rt_field          = name
    rt_attr_uint      = created_by_id
    rt_attr_uint      = category_id

    path              = /var/data/items_item
    docinfo           = extern
    morphology        = none
    min_word_len      = 2
    charset_type      = utf-8

    # "example" with min_prefix_len=3 -> "exa", "exam", "examp", "exampl"    
    min_prefix_len    = 0

    # "test" with min_infix_len=2 -> "te", "es", "st", "tes", "est" 
    min_infix_len     = 0
}

index reviews_feedback
{
    type              = rt

    # List all fields
    rt_field          = body
    rt_attr_uint      = created_by_id
    rt_attr_uint      = is_positive
    rt_attr_uint      = item_id

    path              = /var/data/reviews_feedback
    docinfo           = extern
    morphology        = none
    stopwords         = sphinx_fedbacks_stopwords.txt
    min_word_len      = 2
    charset_type      = utf-8

    # "example" with min_prefix_len=3 -> "exa", "exam", "examp", "exampl"    
    min_prefix_len    = 0

    # "test" with min_infix_len=2 -> "te", "es", "st", "tes", "est" 
    min_infix_len     = 0   
}

indexer
{
    # memory limit, in bytes, kilobytes (16384K) or megabytes (256M)
    # optional, default is 32M, max is 2047M, recommended is 256M to 1024M
    mem_limit           = 32M

    # maximum IO calls per second (for I/O throttling)
    # optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
    max_iops            = 60
}

searchd
{
    listen = localhost:3307:mysql41

    # log file, searchd run info is logged here
    # optional, default is 'searchd.log'
    # log               = /usr/local/sphinx/log/searchd.log

    # query log file, all search queries are logged here
    # optional, default is empty (do not log queries)
    # query_log         = /usr/local/sphinx/log/query.log
    # query_log_format  = 'sphinxql'

    # client read timeout, seconds
    # optional, default is 5
    read_timeout        = 5

    # maximum amount of children to fork (concurrent searches to run)
    # optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
    max_children        = 30

    # PID file, searchd process ID file name
    # mandatory
    pid_file            = /usr/local/sphinx/log/searchd.pid

    # max amount of matches the daemon ever keeps in RAM, per-index
    # WARNING, THERE'S ALSO PER-QUERY LIMIT, SEE SetLimits() API CALL
    # default is 1000 (just like Google)
    max_matches         = 1000

    # seamless rotate, prevents rotate stalls if precaching huge datasets
    # optional, default is 1
    seamless_rotate     = 1

    # whether to forcibly preopen all indexes on startup
    # optional, default is 0 (do not preopen)
    preopen_indexes     = 0

    # whether to unlink .old index copies on succesful rotation.
    # optional, default is 1 (do unlink)
    unlink_old          = 1

    workers = threads
}
```

The indexer skips the RT indexes; and searchd, as I understand, needs *.lock files which is indicated in the path.

So how can I create those lock files?

Comment: It’s not that you need to create lock files—rather, it looks like the Sphinx user doesn’t have permission to create them, which it should. Make sure the user Sphinx is running under has permission to write to `/var/data`.

Comment: @icktoofay, you're right, thanks. So foolish I posted the question here without trying that :/

Answer (score 1):

The common cause of this problem is that your sphinx instance didn't had a clean shutdown and the `lock` files from previous run still exist. In order to run your instance again you must first delete the old `lock` files and try to start your instance.